# Factory method for a generic implementation class

Tags: java

There is a generic interface:

```
public interface IMyQueue<T> {
  //...
}
```

and there is a generic class implementing it:

```
public class MyQueueImp<T> implements IMyQueue<T> {
  //...
}
```

I want the implementation to have a factory method: a public static method `getInstance` that instantiate an object for that generic class.

```
public class MyQueueImp<T> implements IMyQueue<T> {
  public static IMyQueue getInstance() {
     ///....
  }
}
```

So I can call it like this:

```
IMyQueue<Integer> queue = MyQueueImpl.getInstance();
```

The problem is within this static methods there is not access to generic `T`:

```
MyPriorityQueueImpl.this' cannot be referenced from a static context
```

I'm wondering how should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your factory method is static, so it knows nothing of the actual argument for `T`. You would have to declare it on the method itself:

```
public static <U> IMyQueue<U> getInstance() {
   return new MyQueueImp<U>(); //or whatever instantiation you have
}
```

Side note: it's a bit strange to have an `IMyQueue` factory in one specific implementation of `IMyQueue`. Perhaps a better place to put this factory method is a separate class, or you could even put it in `IMyQueue` itself.

Comment: but if I put it in the interface and keep it static, then I have to provide implementation for it. How should it be implemented not knowing which implementation is going to be used?

Comment: I guess that's the point of a factory. Your factory returns an object of that interface type, it decides which implementation to give. If your `getInstance()` method is just to create a `MyQueueImp` object, then it's more like a constructor, and maybe `getInstance()` should be returning `MyQueueImp<U>`.